# JAVA: failing to get encrypted data in string using xor

Tags: java, xor

I was trying to print encrypted text using string perhaps i was wrong somewhere. I am doing simple xor on a plain text. Coming encrypted text/string i am putting in a C program and doing same xor again to get plain text again.

But in between, I am not able to get proper string of encrypted text to pass in C

```
String xorencrypt(byte[] passwd,int pass_len){
    char[] st = new char[pass_len];
    byte[] crypted = new byte[pass_len];
    for(int i = 0; i<pass_len;i++){
        crypted[i] = (byte) (passwd[i]^(i+1));
        st[i] = (char)crypted[i];
        System.out.println((char)passwd[i]+" "+passwd[i] +"= " + (char)crypted[i]+"   "+crypted[i]);/* characters are printed fine but problem is when i am convering it in to string */
    }
    return st.toString();
}
```

I don't know if any kind of encoding also needed because if i did so how I will decode and decrypt from C program.

example if suppose `passwd = bond007`

then java program should return `akkb78>`

further C program will decrypt `akkb78>` to `bond007` again.

Comment: Why do you need `pass_len` parameter ? `pass_len` can be a local variable initialized with `pass.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
return new String(crypted);
```

in that case you don't need `st[]` array at all.

By the way, the encoded value for `bond007` is cmm`560 and not what you posted.

**EDIT**
While solution above would most likely work in most java environments, to be safe about encoding,
as suggested by *Alex*, provide encoding parameter to String constructor. 
For example if you want your string to carry 8-bit bytes :

```
return new String(crypted, "ISO-8859-1");
```

You would need the same parameter when getting bytes from your string :

```
byte[] bytes = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")
```

Alternatively, use solution provided by *Alex* :

```
return new String(st);
```

But, convert `bytes` to `chars` properly :

```
st[i] = (char) (crypted[i] & 0xff);
```

Otherwise, all negative bytes, `crypted[i] < 0` will not be converted to `char` properly and you get surprising results.

Comment: In this case, you assume that charset used in the byte array (`cypted` variable) is the platform default charset.

Comment: @Alex. You are right, there should be extra param to specify encoding. Please, note, however, that simple conversion from byte -> char in line `st[i] = (char)crypted[i];` will get very funny results for bytes values < 0; I will update my answer with this caveats.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
return st.toString();
```

with this

```
return new String(st);
```